# Google app engine setup from checkout project from svn

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps

I am trying to do salesforce Single sign on using google app engine. I am refering this document [Single Sign On](http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth/wiki/Setup#Google_App_Engine_set_up) . In this document I am stuck on Google App Engine set up. in first point 1) Create a new project from "Checkout Projects from SVN" I am not able to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you posted this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114580/google-app-engine-setup-from-checkout-project-from-svn) as well (not sure if it's answered there). From that thread, it's clear that you are using the wrong repo URL. It should be `http://sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/` and NOT `https://code.google.com/p/sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth/source/checkout`